# Haskell - how to wire together components that have different subsets of dependencies?

Tags: haskell, dependency-injection

How can I integrate an application from components that require various subsets of infrastructure functionality?

Some will be very simple and only require a configuration reader (I want to expose only a relevant subset for each business function) and maybe a logger. Some will also require connectivity to external services (with cache) where I also want to expose a limited scope of possible interactions with outside world.

I don't want to deal with passing multiple arguments to such functions explicitly or wrapping them in some `MonadIO` capable of doing everything.

What would be closest thing to injecting **multiple** dependencies as in Java application containers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [mtl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) library has type classes to represent computations that read configuration from an environment, `MonadReader`, and write data to something like a logger, `MonadWriter`. We'll use these for our examples.

The portion of `MonadReader` we will use is

```
class Monad m => MonadReader r m | m -> r where
    ask :: m r
```

The portion of `MonadWriter` we will use is

```
class (Monoid w, Monad m) => MonadWriter w m | m -> w where Source  
    tell :: w -> m ()
```

To require "**multiple** dependencies", we will require a single `m` that provides instances for multiple type classes.

#### Boilerplate

Ultimately, we'll use `ReaderT` and `WriterT` and `Identity` from [transformers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers) to run our example.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

--mtl
import Control.Monad.Reader.Class
import Control.Monad.Writer.Class

--transformers
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader hiding (ask)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Strict hiding (tell)
import Data.Functor.Identity
```

#### Using multiple dependencies: reading configuration and logging

Our reader will read from the following environment; it will provide a `MonadReader Configuration`.

```
data Configuration = Config { site :: String }
    deriving Show
```

Our logger will accumulate a list of messages, each of which is a string. It will provide a `MonadWriter [String]`.

You can require multiple capabilities by requiring instances of multiple type classes. To do so, you can require a single `m` that has instances for both `MonadReader` and `MonadWriter`.  Here's a component that requires an environment to read configuration from and a way to write log messages.

```
logConfig :: (MonadWriter String m, MonadReader Configuration m) => m ()
logConfig = do 
    config <- ask
    tell [show config]
```

#### Providing multiple dependencies with transformers

We can provide the necessary `m` without touching `IO`. `ReaderT` from transformers adds the ability to read from an environment to a `Monad`; we'll use this to provide the `MonadReader Configuration`. `WriterT` from transformers adds that ability to accumulate output to a `Monad`; we'll use this to provide the `MonadWriter [String]`. For the underlying `Monad`, we'll just use `Identity` to show off that we aren't messing with `IO`. The following provides both `MonadReader Configuration` and `MonadWriter [String]`, and runs the computation without using `IO`.

```
type DepsIdentity =  ReaderT Configuration (WriterT [String] Identity)

runDepsIdentity :: DepsIdentity a -> Configuration -> (a, [String])
runDepsIdentity ma = runIdentity . runWriterT . runReaderT ma
```

#### Running an example

We'll use our earlier `logConfig` in another, larger example:

```
example :: (MonadWriter [String] m, MonadReader Configuration m) => m ()
example = do
    tell ["Starting", "Logging Config"]
    logConfig
    tell ["Done Logging Config", "Done"]
```

Finally, we'll run `example` with a `Configuration` and see what it does. Note that the `IO` here is only used to output the final result for the purpose of running an example.

```
main :: IO ()
main = print . runDepsIdentity example $ Config {site = "StackOverflow"}
```

This produces the following output

```
((),["Starting","Logging Config","Config {site = \"StackOverflow\"}","Done Logging Config","Done"])
```